# Property 'getType' does not exist on type 'typeof import

Tags: angular, angular12

I am upgrading from Angular 12 to Angular 13 - when building I get some errors in the terminal

```
Error: src/app/components/feeds/replies/reply.ts:81:31 - error TS2339: Property 'getType' does not exist on type 'typeof import("/Users/me/Sites/app-ng/node_modules/@types/mime/index")'.

81         const mimeType = mime.getType(item) || '';
```

I have checked the code and the `getType` does exist on mime class (I can control click in the file and it opens the relevant file fine) - anyone know why this error occurs and how I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Previous versions of Mime (2.x and 3.x) rely on external type definitions (@types/mime) and there were/are issues with the definitions.

From [4.0.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mime/v/4.0.0) onward TS support is built-in and this issue is now gone.

So just

```
npm i mime@latest
```

and carry on.